# Why is my regex returning None?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

My regex is only matching when I don't include 'or' options; however I need to include that because I will need to match different strings.

```
entries[0] = 'ephname = /share/old/eph/2004A.1770.comb'
print re.search(r'\s?ephname\s?=\s?.*?\.s(\d+).*?\s?|\s?ephname\s?=\s?.*?(\d+)
\.comb\s?', entries[0]).group(1)
>>> None
```

But if I do this instead it works:

```
print re.search(r'\s?ephname\s?=\s?.*?(\d+)\.comb\s?', entries[0]).group(1)
>>> 1770
```

I can't figure out why the first attempt isn't matching anything. Anyone know why?

Comment: Because [it is in Group 2 if you use your first regex](https://regex101.com/r/Gc2KzX/1).

Comment: Ah, thank you! Is there a way I can get it to print only whichever group is not None?

Comment: No idea what your requirements are, but maybe [this](https://ideone.com/RCyj1B) will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It *is* matching; it returned a *match* object, not `None`; and you call `.group(1)` on that match object.

However the problem here that there are now *2* capture groups. The first is in the first branch, and the second in the second branch.

You can store the match into a variable, then use the [`lastindex` property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match.lastindex) to get the index of the last matched capturing group:

```
m = re.search(r'\s?ephname\s?=\s?.*?\.s(\d+).*?\s?'
              r'|\s?ephname\s?=\s?.*?(\d+)\.comb\s?', entries[0])
if m:
    print(m.group(m.lastindex))
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first regex, group 1 is before the `|`, so it’s in a branch that contains `\.s`. No part of your string can match that (you don’t have a literal `.` followed by a literal `s`), so that entire branch fails. The other branch succeeds, but it has a different group number to let you know which alternative worked.